# how to get time avg from mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Well, I have an documents like to

```
{_id:...,created_at:ISODate("2015-07-18T10:23:01.000Z")},
{_id:...,created_at:ISODate("2015-07-18T10:45:01.000Z")},
{_id:...,created_at:ISODate("2015-07-18T11:34:02.000Z")},
{_id:...,created_at:ISODate("2015-07-18T12:26:03.000Z")},
{_id:...,created_at:ISODate("2015-07-18T13:55:00.000Z")}
{_id:...,created_at:ISODate("2015-07-18T15:55:00.000Z")}
{_id:...,created_at:ISODate("2015-07-18T18:55:00.000Z")}
```

So, I will need get avg time(hour) between x and y like

```
{from: "10:25:00",to:"13:55:00"}
```

Where `from` is best hour and `to` is the end of best hour.

I learn about `$avg` and `$group`, but i don't know how to create a average hour...

My collection is a views/sessions register, so then each document equals a visit/activity and i want to get the avg time of access or use.

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking here? Because it is not very clear. Do you want, 1. The number of acesses in a time period? 2. Average time spent on a session based on activity logs? 3 Something else?

Comment: Well i want get avg time between start to end, so if you have activity between 12am and 14pm, but since 15pm to next day u have a pour activity the avg is 12am to 14pm.

Comment: See what I was getting at is your question is "very light" on required information to solve a problem. Show more about the structure of the documents. Clearly define what an "activity" is and so on. There is not enough information here to clearly see what you really want to do.

Comment: well, i said "this collecion is views/sessions, so then each document equals a visit/activity. the logic by group is `{$group:{ _id:$time, hits:{$sum:1}}}`